# How to capture specific group data on Facebook

Tags: facebook, api

I haven't done any programming in a while and I'm a newbie to using the FB API. Therefore, before I dive into it, I wanted to find out 1) if what's trying to be done is possible (and how) and 2) if so, could someone point me to resources that could help me get the task done?

1-Is it possible to programmatically capture all events that have happened in a group that I manage on FB (e.g., number of members, number of posts by member X, number of likes by member X, shares, views, etc.)? If so, does this require a simple script (php, python, java) that can be run at any time or a more complex FB application?

2-Are there any resources that you could suggest I refer to before starting the task (assuming this can be done)?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've addressed my own question. For others that may find this beneficial, check out the Graph API: developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference and common user scenarios: developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios.